# 8788 Patches Help and Advice

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, patches

I have installed 8788v1 but I have noticed that v2 has been release but following the Magento instructions which are very vague it says to revert the patch. But I cant find it on the site, I have found their GitHub repo but there is a syntax error on the patch file that I need. I have never heard of reverting a patch before. It seems like an awful lot of work.

We also use version control so the patch is not uploaded. Once it has been installed it is removed from the client folder.

Any advice on how best to solve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is on the Magento website: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#apply-8788. I think that should help you out.

Comment: Thanks but with the patch already installed, how do I revert it as the patch is not in the root folder? Also I have tried adding the patch file, and then using the -R command to revert it I have received a huge amount of errors. So 8788v1 was installed. I then installed 3941 I then tried to add the old v1 patch and then -R but I got errors. Could I just install v2. There is no real help from Magento on this.